# Kubernetes and readinessprobe

Tags: kubernetes

I have specified a deployment in kubernetes :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: quote-data
    namespace: default
  spec:
    progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
    replicas: 2
    revisionHistoryLimit: 10
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        run: quote-data
    strategy:
      rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
      type: RollingUpdate
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          run: quote-data
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: quote-data:2
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: quote-data
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/data/health
              port: 5000
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 1
            successThreshold: 1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
            protocol: TCP
```

Can we use the readinessprobe to disable the traffic for this pod (few minutes after the start phase) ?

In my test, the service (type: LoadBalancer) continue to send the traffic on the bad pod even if the readinessprobe is failed. In the service, the Ready status of the pod = false but the service still continues to send on the wrong pod

UPDATE :
it seems work with a curl but not with Postman.
I have a pods different between two request with a simple curl command.
I have always the same pod with Postman

Comment: Hi, you can increase **initialDelaySeconds** thus kubelet will till that amount of second to do its first probe.

Comment: Have you tried to include liveness probe in order to check the further behavior?

Comment: I found the explanation of my problem. In fact, postman keeps an open http connection with the htttp1.1 protocol

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the traffic will be disabled if you put initialDelaySeconds: xxx on readinessProbe. For this is not working on all Kubernetes version, for sure not on 1.15 and bellow.